# How to query Id of a field from standard object

Tags: tooling-api

How do I get the Id of the field on Standard object like Account, Opportunity from Apex? Tooling API helps in getting the Custom Object and Custom Field Id.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The standard salesforce fields have their own standard IDs (names). [Here is the list](http://www.salesforcefast.com/2012/09/what-are-standard-objects-field-ids.html)

Comment: What if I add a custom field on standard object.. I added a custom field and it's Id is 15 character alphanumeric. Right now I have to store the ID of the field in custom setting which is not a elegant solution as the Id will differ between environments. Hence wanted to retrieve the IDs dynamically in code.

Comment: Unfortunately the tooling API doesn't support that scenario at the moment. You can do that with this old hack (if that helps) - https://force201.wordpress.com/2014/02/27/finding-visualforce-field-ids/